# Getting weird error: "Error:Hidden field value (not shown) duplicates value on record: LANDesk Software Ltd"

Tags: error, hidden-fields

When trying to close out an Opp, I get this error:

"Error:Hidden field value (not shown) duplicates value on record: LANDesk Software Ltd"

The crazy part is, the Opp is related to a different Account, "Ivanti".

From the limited researched I found online, it has to do with what the error says, duplicates values on a record with a field that should be a unique ID/value.

When I went through the Accounts and looked at all fields that are unique, I didn't see any issues, so I assume it's some automation that is updating the Account with a value that is in conflict with another Account.

I'm struggling to debug this. Not very knowledgeable about debugging, so while I think I know the issue, it's very hard to decipher exactly what's happening.

Looking for instructions to understand what is happening behind the scenes causing this error to pop-up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The starting point for debugging server-side logic is to turn on the debug logging. See [Set Up Debug Logging](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_add_users_debug_log.htm&type=5) - its easier than it looks from that page and Salesforce have made the default debug levels a pretty good compromise.

One log file is produced per request, so try to do the close then go and look at the latest log file. Scroll through that file to see what is going on. It will be quite long so first scan over it and then focus on particular areas; your browsers search feature (Crtl+F) can be handy to quickly find things. If you are lucky that will guide you to the problem area.

You can also repeat this having adjusted the log levels to generate more detail if you don't find anything using the default levels.